# Close select box container after selecting an option. Conflicting code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a few different scripts that seem to be conflicting each other in some way. Open to suggestions for a better code to use for the content swapping part of this. I like the style and function of the dropdown select options.

The first script is this one from Codrops:
http://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index4.html

And I'm combining that styling with the content swap functionality found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Artsen/gDPJG/

The function of the Codrops example works great on my site until I add the content swap code.

Here's what (I think) controls the closing of the select options after clicking on an option:

Line 238 of selectFx.js from Codrops::

```
/**
 * open/close select
 * when opened show the default placeholder if any
 */
SelectFx.prototype._toggleSelect = function() {
    // remove focus class if any..
    this._removeFocus();

    if( this._isOpen() ) {
        if( this.current !== -1 ) {
            // update placeholder text
            this.selPlaceholder.textContent = this.selOpts[ this.current ].textContent;
        }
        classie.remove( this.selEl, 'cs-active' );
    }
    else {
        if( this.hasDefaultPlaceholder && this.options.stickyPlaceholder ) {
            // everytime we open we wanna see the default placeholder text
            this.selPlaceholder.textContent = this.selectedOpt.textContent;
        }
        classie.add( this.selEl, 'cs-active' );
    }
}
```

And the code added for the content swap that removed the close functionality:

```
    $('.info-container div').hide();

$('.div-toggler li a').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') == true) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('.info-container div').fadeOut();
        var contentToLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        $(contentToLoad).delay(400).fadeIn("slow");

        return false;
    }


});
```

The current working copy is here..  unreasonable.institute/network

With the select items appearing as they should, the content swapping as it should, but the options remain on the page after selecting one. It should close like the Codrops example.

Comment: working copy link is wrong. please correct it.

Comment: I wasn't able to add more than two links, the third was without http:// 

Here is is, sorry: [Institute Programs](http://unreasonable.institute/programs/)